# Why is $\log_{10}\pi \simeq 0.5$?

Tags: logarithms, pi

I was looking at my slide rule earlier today, and happened to notice that the dedicated mark for $\pi$ is right around the middle of the scale:

[image: slide rule with pi circled]

Of course, this is because $\log_{10}\pi \simeq 0.4971498$, which is very close to $1\over2$.

Is there a reason or derivation for this, or is it pure coincidence?

Comment: Wow, that brings back memories.  I haven't seen a slide rule for years.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I've never used it!

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "This coincidence was used in the design of slide rules, where the "folded" scales are folded on $\pi$ rather than 
$\sqrt{10}$ because it is a more useful number and has the effect of folding the scales in about the same place"

Comment: That page on [Mathematical coincidences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_coincidence) also notes that this is the reason the gravitational constant $g\approx10 m/s^2$, because a meter was originally defined as the length of a pendulum with a half period of 1 second, and $T_{1\over2}\approx\pi\sqrt{L\over{g}} \implies g\approx\pi^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\pi^2\approx 10$ is not a coincidence. Since $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ we have
$$ \pi^2 = 6+\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{6}{n^2} \leq 6+\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{6}{n^2-\frac{1}{4}}=10 $$
and the difference between the RHS and the LHS is
$$ 10-\pi^2=\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{6}{n^2(4n^2-1)}\leq \frac{1}{10}+\sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{24}{(4n^2-9)(4n^2-1)}=\frac{29}{210}. $$

Comment: How is the $\sum\limits_{n \geq 2} \frac{6}{n^2-1/4}=4$?

Comment: Why it should demonstrate that it is not a coincidence? I don't see the reason.

Comment: @Botond: that is a telescopic series.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks, I'm going to check it.

Comment: @Botond: you may also have a look at the first section of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view) where the identity $\pi^2=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{18}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}\approx 10$ is proved through creative telescoping.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I've saved your notes before. I saw a lot of awesome stuff in it, but It was hard to understand due to the lack of my knowledge. I want to learn more analysis in the close future (but it's quite hard to take analysis courses for mathematicians while having the physics classes), so It will be useful later.

Answer (score 7):

Simply because

$$\sqrt{10}=10^{\frac12}\approx 3.16 \approx \pi$$

indeed

$$y=\log_{10}\pi\iff10^y=\pi$$

thus

$$y\approx \frac12$$

Comment: I don't feel like this answer addresses OP's core question, "Is there a reason or derivation for this, or is it pure coincidence?"

Comment: @ChrisCulter Interesting point! I'll think about it, post also your own answer if you have some idea to share!

Comment: @ChrisCulter I think gimusi showed its reason: $\pi^2 \approx 10$. Maybe the $\Delta \log(a) < \Delta a$ could be added.

Comment: @ChrisCulter Anyway I think it is just a coincidence, indeed it is expressed in base-ten (for counting) which is an arbitrary choice. I'm wondering how it should be in base-2 or others.

Comment: @Botond Well, why is $\pi^2\approx10$? A satisfactory explanation would involve some argument beyond rearranging the equation and performing a numerical evaluation. If someone asks you why $\pi\approx3$, you don't evaluate some series and conclude that $3.14\approx3$; you should be drawing a regular hexagon inscribed in a circle. If someone asks why $\pi\approx\frac{22}{7}$, you should start talking about $\int_0^1 \frac{x^4\left(1-x\right)^4}{1+x^2} \, dx$. For $\pi^2\approx10$, Jack D'Aurizio suggests that the answer is implied by $\zeta(2)$; and there could be other explanations as well.

Comment: @ChrisCulter Why is $\pi^2 \approx 10$? I think it's a "bad" question. It's like "Why is $2.01 \approx 2$?

Answer (score 4):

I cannot see a very deep reason why this would be so, but the continued fraction of $\sqrt{10}$ is $3 + \frac{1}{6 + \frac{1}{6 + \cdots}}$ and a continued fraction for $\pi$ is $3 + \frac{1}{6 + \frac{9}{6 + \cdots}}$ so they at least agree to $3 + \frac{1}{6}$, which after all is not too bad of an estimate, being off by only 2 in the second decimal place.

I suppose it is worth noting that a general continued fraction for square roots of the form $\sqrt{a^2 + b} = a + \frac{b}{2a + \frac{b}{2a + \cdots}}$ then there is straightforwardly *no better* approximation to $\pi$ by the square root of an integer since $a$ is constrained to be $3$ and $b$ is constrained to be $1$ right at the start.

I'm not sure how to consider things "coincidental" at this level of navel gazing.

Answer (score 2):

$$\pi \approx 3.141592654 \implies log(\pi ) \approx .497149873$$ 
$$ \sqrt 10 \approx 3.162277660 \implies log \sqrt {10} =.5$$

They are not equal but very close.

Comment: Your value of pi has a typo. 3.1*4*

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer  Thanks for the comment. I fixed it per your advice.